# how to sync encryption between delphi and php using dcpcrypt

Tags: php, delphi, mcrypt

I'm using Delphi 2009 and most of the answers I've seen here are for 2010+
I am trying to sync encryption (delphi) to decryption (php) and failing.

generate the encrypted string in delphi:

```
program Project4;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  DCPcrypt2,
  DCPsha1,
  DCPblockciphers,
  DCPdes,
  EncdDecd;

var des: tdcp_des;
    enc,dec: ansistring;

begin
  try
  des:=tdcp_des.Create(nil);
  des.InitStr('test', tdcp_sha1);
  enc:=encodestring(des.EncryptString('this is a test'));
  des.Free;

  des:=tdcp_des.Create(nil);
  des.InitStr('test', tdcp_sha1);
  dec:=des.DecryptString(decodestring(enc));
  des.Free;

  writeln(enc);
  writeln(dec);
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

decrypt in php:

```
<?php
function decrypt($str, $key)
{
    $size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_DES, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);
    $data = base64_decode($str);
    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('des', 'ecb');
    $k = substr(sha1($key), 0, $block);
    $str = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $k, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $pad = ord($str[($len = strlen($str)) - 1]);
    return substr($str, 0, strlen($str) - $pad);
}

$enc = 'TW5mbVFhODUyR2FoOTA2WWJIOD0=';
$dec = decrypt($enc, 'test');
echo "$dec\n";
?>
```

Comment: I see no reason there would be significant difference in this code between Delphi 2009 and Delphi 2010. How are you "failing"?

Comment: The output of the decrypt is null

Comment: @Daniel in <des.InitStr('test', tdcp_sha1);> "test" is a unicode string, try <des.InitStr(AnsiString('test'), tdcp_sha1);>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several issues, I think :-)

- des.InitStr() internally creates an IV from 8 null bytes which it then encrypts. You need to use the same IV in your PHP.
- The sha1($key) produces a hex string rather than the actual bytes of the password. You need something like mhash instead.
- I couldn't manage to reproduce your $enc string with the given Delphi function.
- Unicode issues - the password and source text are going to be treated as unicode in Delphi.
- You seem to be base 64 encoding the source twice in the Delphi routines. des.EncryptString and des.DecryptString produce and consume base 64 encoded strings so no need to do it again.
- Padding

Based on my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7078230/197962) - this is my suggestion:

```
function EncryptStringDES: string;
var
  des: TDCP_des;
  src, enc, b64: TBytes;
  index, slen, bsize, padsize: integer;
begin
  des:=tdcp_des.Create(nil);
  try
    des.InitStr(AnsiString('test'), tdcp_sha1);

    src := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('this is a test');
    slen := Length(src);
    // Add padding
    bsize := des.BlockSize div 8;
    padsize := bsize - (slen mod bsize);
    Inc(slen, padsize);
    SetLength(src, slen);
    for index := padsize downto 1 do
    begin
      src[slen - index] := padsize;
    end;

    SetLength(enc, slen);
    des.EncryptCBC(src[0], enc[0], slen);
    result := EncdDecd.EncodeBase64(@enc[0], Length(enc));
  finally
    des.Free;
  end;
end;

function DecryptStringDES(ASource: string): string;
var
  des: TDCP_des;
  key, src, dec, b64: TBytes;
  pad, slen: integer;
begin
  des := TDCP_des.Create(nil);
  try
    des.InitStr(AnsiString('test'), tdcp_sha1);

    src := EncdDecd.DecodeBase64(AnsiString(ASource));
    slen := Length(src);
    SetLength(dec, slen);
    des.DecryptCBC(src[0], dec[0], slen);

    // Remove padding
    pad := dec[slen - 1];
    SetLength(dec, slen - pad);

    result := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(dec);
  finally
    des.Free;
  end;
end;
```

and the PHP:

```
<?php
function decrypt_SO($str, $key)
{
    //$ivsize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_DES, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    //$blocksize = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_DES, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $keysize = mcrypt_get_key_size(MCRYPT_DES, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);

    // Need to use the SAME IV as the Delphi function. By default
    // this is (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) encrypted using ECB mode and gives the
    // following bytes:
    $ivbytes = array(72, 163, 99, 62, 219, 111, 163, 114);
    $iv = implode(array_map("chr", $ivbytes));

    $enc = base64_decode($str);
    $k = mhash(MHASH_SHA1, $key);
    $dec = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_DES, substr($k, 0, $keysize), $enc, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    $pad = ord($dec[strlen($dec) - 1]);
    return substr($dec, 0, strlen($dec) - $pad);
}

$enc = 'WRaG/8xlxqqcTAJ5UAk4DA==';
$dec = decrypt_SO($enc, 'test');
echo "$dec\n";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if password is longer than 4 symbols, some first characters of decoded string is in wrong encoding. I use openssl openssl_decrypt($enc, $alg, $k, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);

Comment: Oh it's my fail( IV changes on any password change. So, I've got different IV for php and delphi. 
`const iV: array[0..7] of Byte = (203, 28, 194, 82, 254, 109, 60, 181);
 vCipher.SetIV(iv);` It Helped me to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

who is the iv bytes

```
$ivbytes = array(72, 163, 99, 62, 219, 111, 163, 114);
```

for the key: test123456

```
$ivbytes = array(??, ??, ??, ??, ??, ??, ??, ??);
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this kind of integration with success but i cant provide more information than that, it belongs to my employer.

did you initialized mycrypt?

```
$iv = "nononono";
$key = "nononono";
$td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
$decoded = base64_decode($mySecretString);
$decryptedcbc = mdecrypt_generic($td, $decoded);
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
```

dont forget to encode your string properly in delphi, i use Base64EncodeStr(Buffer);

i hope it helps.